# Javascript Promises in React onClick Handler

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise

I have a React component where I am updating the UI twice in an onClick handler: once right away, and a second time after a promise is completed.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    handleClick() {
        this.setState({...})
        new Promise((resolve) => {
            let data = doSomeProcessing()
            resolve(data)
        }).then(data => {
            this.setState({...})
        })
    }

    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that both updates happen (visually) at the same time, after a delay corresponding to the time it takes for the promise to complete. How do I get the first update to happen right away, and the second update to happen whenever the promise is completed?

I also tried moving the promise into `componentDidUpdate` but the same thing happened.

Thanks for the help!

**Update:**

I tried doing this and it seems to sort of work:

```
handleClick() {
    this.setState({...})
}

componentDidMount() {
    if (condition) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            new Promise((resolve) => {
                let data = doSomeProcessing()
                resolve(data)
            }).then(data => {
                this.setState({...})
            })
        }, 100)
    }
}
```

With a delay of 100ms it works every time (i.e. I see the first update, then the second). With a delay of 1ms it never works (i.e. I see nothing, then both updates at the once). With a delay of 10ms it works some of the time. So maybe there's some sort of race condition? But from my understanding, by that time that `componentDidUpdate` is called, the UI should have already updated.

Comment: Have you tried placing the promise inside callback function of [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: Just tried it and it seems to be having the same result